# Appending dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas

Append is not working using for loop in python

> It is working without for loop but It's not working using for loop

```
import os as o
import pandas as pd
j=0
ls=[]
files = o.listdir("demo")
for i in files:
  ls.append(i)
df=pd.read_csv("demo/"+ls[0])
t=len(ls)
for i in range(1,t):
  temp=pd.read_csv("demo/"+ls[i])
  df.append(temp,ignore_index = True)
print(df)
```

Comment: It is working, it's just not doing what you think it is doing. You **shouldn't do this to begin with, it is highly inefficient**. Use `pd.concat` with a list of data-frames.

Comment: `pd.concat([pd.read_csv("demo/"+ls[i]) for i in range(1,t)], ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Thanks @ALollz It's working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using df.append is highly inefficient, you should instead

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv("demo/"+ls[i]) for i in range(1, len(ls))]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(1,t):
  temp=pd.read_csv("demo/"+ls[i])
  df = df.append(temp,ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: Few days back I made this same mistake.

Answer (score -1):

How about using:

```
    dfs = list()
    for file_ in os.listdir("demo"):
        dfs.append(pd.read_csv("demo/"+file_))
    df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: This doesn't work, you should read first the docs of pd.concat it takes a iterable of pd.DataFrames

Comment: @AlessandroSolbiati  to me, a list is iterable. I dunno about you. I suggest you read the docs of Python List, and check yourself before downvoting.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to be harsh, what I meant is that if in your code above `dfs` and`df` will not yield the desired result. Also, the problem here is the low performance of calling `dfs.append` multiple times in the iteration, I would recommend to try out your code and check out what is in `dfs` and what is in `df`

Comment: @AlessandroSolbiati You should at least try before you come down to state "This doesn't work". I have tried it and it works fine. Maybe I can agree on the part of dfs.append, I could use a list comprehension, but I didn't want to.